# Zero in first of my cell data will remove in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am trying to export my data to excel with PHPExcel,
I have a column which many of data on this column will start with `0` for example `0054672351` or `057524572` .

Now when I am trying to export to excel, my data will change to `54672351` or `57524572`.

I am trying to change Data format of this column to text but I have this problem yet !

What should I do ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the second time of answering this same question here today:

Either:

```
// Set the value explicitly as a string
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValueExplicit(
        'A1', 
        '0054672351', 
        PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING
    );
```

or

```
// Set the value as a number formatted with leading zeroes
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue('A3', 54672351);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('A3')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode('0000000000');
```

Note that in the first case I'm calling the setCellValueExplicit() method, not the setCellValue() method.

If you're populating blocks of data in one step using the fromArray() method, then the latter approach is probably easier, especially as you can set the style for a whole block of cells in one step once you've populated all the data.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('A3:A123')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode('0000000000');
```

Comment: Thank you, I searched before but I didn't found any solution so I ask question here, anyway, thank you for your help.